# How to fix ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle sql, this code would have worked in tsql, but does not seem to work in oracle sql. I get a

> **ORA-00918:** column ambiguously defined

. I cant spot where the issue is, can you help ?

the problem seem to be in the join, because when i replace the join with a simple where clause, the error goes away

```
WITH cte1 AS
   (select t1.CONTAINER_NUMBER        as t1_CONTAINER_NUMBER,
           t1.LAST_UPDATE_TIME        as t1_LAST_UPDATE_TIME,
           t1.TRANSACTION_TIME        as t1_TRANSACTION_TIME,
           t1.EVENT,
           t1.LINE_OPERATOR,
           t1.BOOKING_NUMBER,
           t1.ISO_SIZE_TYPE,
           t1.GROSS_WEIGHT,
           t1.CATEGORY,
           t1.STATUS,
           t1.POS_MODE,
           t1.ARR_MODE,
           t1.ARR_CARRIER,
           t1.ARR_VOYAGE,
           t1.DEP_CARRIER,
           t1.DEP_MODE,
           t1.DEP_CARRIER,
           t1.LOAD_PORT,
           t1.DESTINATION_PORT,
           t1.TRUCKER_LICENSE,
           t1.FROM_RAILCAR_NAME,
           t1.TO_RAILCAR_NAME,
           t1.YARDARRIVAL_TIME,
           t1.YARDDEPARTURE_TIME,
           t1.CUSTOMER_REFERENCE,
           t1.CONTAINER_LENGTH,
           t1.CONTAINER_WIDTH,
           t1.CONTAINER_HEIGHT,
           t1.TERMINAL_ARRIVAL_TIME,
           t1.TERMINAL_DEPARTURE_TIME
      from CONTAINER_HISTORY_MVW t1
     where t1.CONTAINER_NUMBER = 'BEAU2105501'
       and t1.EVENT is not null),
  cte2 AS
   (select t2.CONTAINER_NUMBER      as t2_CONTAINER_NUMBER,
           t2.LAST_UPDATE_TIME      as t2_LAST_UPDATE_TIME,
           t2.TRANSACTION_TIME      as t2_TRANSACTION_TIME,
           t2.CREATION_TIME,
           t2.EQUIPMENT_MOVE_TYPE,
           t2.FROM_EQUIPMENT_NUMBER
      from CONTAINER_HISTORY_MVW t2
     where t2.CONTAINER_NUMBER = 'BEAU2105501'
       and t2.EVENT is null)
  SELECT cte1.t1_TRANSACTION_TIME,
         cte1.t1_CONTAINER_NUMBER,
         cte1.t1_LAST_UPDATE_TIME,
         cte1.EVENT,
         cte1.BOOKING_NUMBER,
         cte2.t2_TRANSACTION_TIME,
         cte2.CREATION_TIME,
         cte2.EQUIPMENT_MOVE_TYPE,
         cte2.FROM_EQUIPMENT_NUMBER
    from cte1
   inner join cte2
      on cte1.t1_CONTAINER_NUMBER = cte2.t2_CONTAINER_NUMBER
     and cte1.t1_LAST_UPDATE_TIME = cte2.t2_LAST_UPDATE_TIME
   order by cte1.t1_TRANSACTION_TIME, cte2.t2_TRANSACTION_TIME
```

Comment: it's hard to read such a huge query. The main principle is detecting repeating common column names among different tables and distinguishingly aliasing them . Did you issue `show error` command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a cut and paste error but only select a column once or you have to alias the second to distinguish it from the first.

```
       t1.DEP_CARRIER,
       t1.DEP_MODE,
       t1.DEP_CARRIER,    -- duplicate column name in cte1
```

Comment: Yes, good catch. Firstly I thought there's no prblem with such a query : `select sysdate dt, sysdate dt from dual` which gives result without problem. But if it's a subquery for a query `with t as
  (
  select sysdate dt, sysdate dt from dual
  )
  select dt 
    from t` yields that ambiguity problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because your columns you have put "as .."
try to format the column outside the WITH query.